# @Version with @LastModifiedDate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

People.
I was thinking about the easiest way to avoid the lost update in spring.
Inside a @Transactional method I am updating persistent object. To avoid the lost update possibility @LastModifiedDate and @Version annotation should deal with it with something like:

```
  @LastModifiedDate
  @Version
  private DateTime updateTime;
```

I think that is a short way to achieve what I need, but do you know any downsides of these? Shall they work as expected? Every piece of info will be greatly appreciated. Best Regards.

Comment: As a note, if you're already using Java 8 types, `Instant` is more appropriate.

Comment: @chrylis hei man. thanks for the answer. can you link a thread or docs with more info for that 'Instant' coz I didn't find at first glance.

Comment: `DateTime` is the Joda class, which was a third-party date/time library that was essentially rolled into Java 8 as `java.time`. There's nothing wrong with it, but it's unnecessary in most new projects.

Comment: Maybe create entityListner which updates your modify time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there are any downsides - it works as expected for me with Spring 5.1.5 and Spring Data JPA 2.1.5. I didn't find anyone complaining neither.

**Edit (10/07/2019)**

The only issue I found is when you use field of `Date` type as your timestamp and it is stored as `DATETIME` in  `MySQL` v5.6 (it has been fixed in `MySQL` v5.7). `DATETIME` precision is down to seconds, so if you have two transactions running in a matter of the same second, version won't be updated and Entity got to the state I couldn't update it anymore.

TLDR - If you're planning to use `@Version` together with `@LastModifiedDate`, make sure that timestamp is stored with precision to at least milliseconds and it may have limitations if you ever access it even more often